# Load SCNScene from a remote server URL

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, scnscene

I am trying to initialize or construct a SCNNode with the following code. It will pull the SCN file from the server and load it in the code. However, it seems like I cannot override the asset URL that it keeps searching for my texture file in device/local directory. I would like to know did I use the correct syntax of the SCNScene with URL

```
lazy var audiNode: SCNNode = {

    //Endpoint for SCN file
    let endpoint = URL(string: "http://jwt-auth-hosted.au-syd.mybluemix.net/hkdl-ar/tree.scn")
    //Remote directory for texture PNG file for the SCN file
    let texture = NSURL(string: "http://jwt-auth-hosted.au-syd.mybluemix.net/hkdl-ar")

    //Declare scene options for initializing SCNScene
    let assetDirURL = SCNSceneSource.LoadingOption.assetDirectoryURLs
    let isOverrideAssetURL = SCNSceneSource.LoadingOption.overrideAssetURLs

    do {
        /*
        - Declare scene with endpoint, is override asset URL = true, asset directory is texture
        - However not sure if the options are being correctly called
        */
        let scene = try SCNScene(url: endpoint!, options: [assetDirURL: [texture],isOverrideAssetURL:{1}])
        //scene is not null
        NSLog("audi scnscene: \(scene) with endpoint: \(String(describing: endpoint))")
    }
    catch let error {
        NSLog("cannot load scnscene")
    }
    //Initialize parent node
    let carNode = SCNNode()

    //Get all child nodes of the SCNScene
    let carSceneChildNodes = scene.rootNode.childNodes
    //Loop through all child nodes and add them into the parent node
    for childNode in carSceneChildNodes {
        carNode.addChildNode(childNode)
    }
    //Set scale and position of the parent node
    let scaleFactor  = 0.05
    carNode.position = SCNVector3(0,0,0)
    carNode.scale = SCNVector3(scaleFactor, scaleFactor, scaleFactor)
    NSLog("returning audi node")
    //return node to another
    return carNode
}()
```

So the error I get is 2018-07-26 19:33:34.582848+0800 ARKit+CoreLocation[28182:11913775] [SceneKit] Error: Failed loading : C3DImage 0x1c08e1780 src:file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/E103CC90-B45B-4111-885C-806328F27D93/ARKit+CoreLocation.app/tree.png [0.000000x0.000000]. I am not sure how to override the asset URL correctly and would be happy that you can help!

Comment: You should download the files first into the app sandbox, then only load into the scene.